# Can I remove some soundtracks from the random pool in CoND?

Tags: crypt-of-the-necrodancer

I like playing Crypt of the Necrodancer with random soundtrack mode enabled for more variety in the soundtracks. However, the latest update added one version of the soundtrack which actually consists of completely different music, which I find jarring (the Danganronpa soundtrack). Unfortunately, this version of the soundtrack can be picked when the chosen soundtrack is set to "random". Is there any way I can exclude just this soundtrack but have the game pick randomly from all the other soundtracks for each floor?

Comment: I worked around this by renaming all the Danganrompa music files and then copying the original soundtrack files in their place, but this now makes the original version of each song twice as likely to be played as all the others, which is workable but not ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not a way to just remove songs from the random pool this way.

Fortunately (for you, at least), a lot of people complained about the sudden addition of the Danganronpa soundtrack and the developers removed it from the random pool. See [this Steam thread, where the developer replied](https://steamcommunity.com/app/247080/discussions/3/2579854400756360326/):

> Thank you for the feedback, we will be doing some updates to fix the issues listed in this thread:
>
> - Taking the Danganronpa soundtrack out of the "random soundtrack" option.
> - Making the Shopkeeper not sing while the Danganronpa soundtrack is being used.
>
> [...]
>
> The Danganronpa content was originally created as an exclusive for the base game in Japan. We were given permission to share it worldwide. This means that the content, such as the soundtrack, only covers Zones 1 through 4. The team and I apologize for any confusion.

From [the Crypt of the Necrodancer update history](http://store.steampowered.com/news/?appids=247080&appgroupname=Crypt+of+the+NecroDancer&headlines=1#), this change apparently was implemented in base version 1.29 and AMPLIFIED! version 2.57:

> Changelog: 
>   Base game v1.29 
>   Amplified v2.57
>
> - The "change skin" option is now usable in the base game.
> - **The Danganronpa soundtrack will not play while using the "random soundtrack" option.**
> - The Shopkeeper will not sing while the Danganronpa soundtrack is used.